# Vectorize function evaluation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have the following function,

```
function Vectorize()
a = randn(1,5)
b = randn(1,5)
c = zeros(1,5)
for i=1:5
c(i) = (a(i) - b(i))/(1+a(i)/2+b(i)/3)
end
```

I want to vectorize the above function evaluation and replace the `for` loop.

I could do `c = a -b`, that finds the difference between two row vectors.I am not sure how to handle the division a/2 and b/2.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the element wise division operation `./`

```
c = (a - b)./(1+a/2+b/3)
```

If you divide a vector by a scalar, this is not required, but where you divide an array by an array you will have to use `./` in your case. See [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/matlab-operators-and-special-characters.html) for the other element wise operators.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying `c = (a - b)/(1+a./2+b./3)` instead.