# Why does vectorizing my Matlab function give me a warning?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am trying to plot the surface `x^2*y^2+y^2*z^2+z^2*x^2=1` in Matlab. I vectorized my function since, as I had learned in a differential equations class that used Matlab, it is good practice. However, Matlab gave me the following warning:

> Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs. To improve
> performance, properly vectorize your function to return an output with
> the same size and shape as the input arguments.

Here is my code:

```
f = @(x,y,z) x.^2.*y.^2+y.^2.*z.^2+z.^2*x.^2-1;
fimplicit3(f)
```

What did I do wrong?

All previous StackOverflow questions on Matlab vectorization (e.g. [Vectorize function evaluation in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53362840/4472547)) involve for loops, it seems.

Comment: Check the last multiplication in your function, it is still `*` not `.*`

Comment: Note that `x.^2.*y.^2` is the same as `(x.*y).^2`, but the latter is faster because it squares only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget single dot
**`z.^2*x.^2-1 ==> z.^2.*x.^2-1;`**

```
f = @(x,y,z) x.^2.*y.^2+y.^2.*z.^2+z.^2.*x.^2-1;
fimplicit3(f)
```